# How to extract the relevant elements from this array of associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following challenging array of associative arrays in php.

```
    array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                    'table' => array(
                            'venue' => 'venue1',
                            'name' => 'name1'                                
                    )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                    'table' => array(
                            'venue' => 'venue1',
                            'name' => 'name2'      
                    )
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                    'table' => array(
                            'venue' => 'venue2',
                            'name' => 'name3'      
                    )
            ),
            (int) 3 => array(
                    'table' => array(
                            'venue' => 'venue3',
                            'name' => 'name4'      
                    )
            )
    )
```

I want to extract a list of relevant names out based on the venue. I would like to implement a function `ExtractNameArray($venue)` such that when `$venue=='venue1'`, the returned array will look like `array('name1', 'name2')`

I have been cracking my head over this. I am starting with $foreach and am stuck. How can this be done in php? Thank you very much.

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: You could modify a multidimensional array search function eg: http://codequake.co.uk/code/php/1/Searching_a_Multidimensional_Array_with_PHP, and instead of just returning true/false if the value you're searching for is found, return an array of keys where the value was found. Then you can get your desired information by looking up those keys.

Comment: There was one answer posted just now which was correct after some modification but was removed. Hope the poster can put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you have to pass the array with the data to the function

second, the name of the function should start with lower character (php conventions)

try this

```
function extractNameArray($array, $venue) {
    $results = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(isset($value['table']['venue'])&&$value['table']['venue']==$venue) {
            isset($value['table']['name']) && $results[] = $value['table']['name'];
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ExtractNameArray($venue) 
{
    $array = array(); // your array 
    $return_array = array();
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr['table'] as $table)
        {
            if($table['venue'] == $venue)
            {
                $return_array[]['name'] = $table['name'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

You must define $array with you array. Good Luck